# C# can't open serial port from application launch successfully

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, settings

So I have this port that I'm opening and saving the name of the port in a setting of my application. When I load the form it tries to open the port however fails to do so. Only after clicking on my "open port" button that has the *EXACT* same code does the port open. And then If I click my "close port" button and reopen the form it works! It automatically opens the port for me. However it's only if I'm fast enough. If I leave the application closed (and thus port closed) for say 10-15 seconds and reopen the application, I'll get my error thrown at me. What's the reason for this??

The code used at launch and in my "open port" button:

```
        mySerialPort.createPort(Properties.Settings.Default.portName);

        if (!mySerialPort.isOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                mySerialPort.openSerialPort();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not open Serial port " + Properties.Settings.Default.portName, "Port Opening Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            if (mySerialPort.isOpen)
            {
                portActiveStatusLbl.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.portName + " OPEN";
                portActiveStatusLbl.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
```

and here's mySerialPort Class:

```
    public static class SerialPortConfig
{
    public static SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort();
    public static string myString = "";
    public static bool isOpen { get { return mySerialPort.IsOpen; } }


    public static void createPort (string portName)
    {
        if (portName == "")
            portName = "COM1";
        mySerialPort.PortName = portName;
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 2400; //Depending on the hardware used this may change, mitutoyo input tool asks for 2400 baud
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend; //DO NOT SET TO NONE

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    public static void openSerialPort()
    {
        mySerialPort.Open();
    }

    public static void closeSerialPort()
    {
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting(); //stores the char that fired the event into 'indata'
        myString += indata;
        if (indata.Contains("\r")) //check to see if char received indicates end of measurement
        {
            if (myString == "911\r") //911 is the code given when the micrometer is off, so we have it do nothing
                myString = "";
            else
            {
                myString = myString.Substring(4, 8);
                Form1.instance.pendingMeasurement = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you post the full code, including the class "mySerialPort" (as this is not the .net SerialPort class) no one would be able to help you.

Comment: @Gusman added it in edit!

Comment: Programmers are *much* too eager to call SerialPort.Close().  That Close call in createPort() is hiding a bug.  Makes no sense at all, delete it and you'll get closer to the real bug.  By far the best time to call Close is *never*.

Comment: Why are you declaring the port as static but your class is not static? Maybe you're creating two different instances of SerialPortConfig? if that's the case it will lead to an unexpected behavior as your serial port will be attached twice to DataReceivedHandler. Also, trap the exception and post the message, it will tell you which happened.

Comment: @HansPassant deleted it but still persisting with the same behaviour. :( good idea though

Comment: @Gusman Okay I've made it a static class and still the same problem exists. I was however very careful to only have one instance of it before so I don't think that was the problem. The exception is "System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready.". So how do I "ready" it?

Comment: `catch(Exception ex){ MessageBox.Show(e.Message + " - " + e.StackTrace); }`

Comment: @Gusman see my edit to the comment above, added the ex info there. But I'll write it again for clarity, "System.IO.IOExcetpion: The device is not ready."

Comment: The stack trace must have told you in which line the exception happens, add it.

Comment: Are you creating an instance of your SerialPortConfig class in your main form code ?

Comment: Also, in any way, you're attaching twice to the event, if the first code is the exact same one as the one you have on the button, you call twice to createPort and that attaches the event again. You aren't checking if the port is open before closing it, also if the port is open you try to change the name before closing it... I would start from zero, that implementation has too many problems, just a non static class, at the constructor create the port and attach events, implement IDisposable and on Dispose unhook the event and close the port, then when you want to disconnect dispose and null it.

Comment: @Gusman trace: System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str) at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(string portName blah blah blah and the lines it gives are line 35 of SerialPortConfig (mySerialPort.Open();) and line 91 of Form1 (SerialPortConfig.openSerialPort();)

Comment: @RobertAltman it's now a static class, I updated my OP just now

Comment: @Gusman I have checks to see if the port is already open when pressing the "open port button". It throws an error if you try to do that so that shouldn't be the problem. I think there's something going on here where the port isn't being warmed up or something. Like I need to somehow ready the port before trying to open it.

Comment: Well, and that's not all, you aren't prepared to read fragmented nor mixed messages, you expect to get one char at a time by your comments, that's not true, you can perfectly receive two messages concatenated, and splitted at the middle, if the system is busy it can buffer the data and when gets time then gives you all the data at once as you're using ReadExisting, you can per example receive something like "911\ranotherdata" so your code would stop working as the var will never be "911\r"

Comment: I guess my next question is, why are you working out of your own created class? You're using the methods that already exist in the SerialPort class. It's just redundant. Have you tried eliminating your class and using only the SerialPort class?

Comment: @Gusman didn't know I was at risk there. How do I account for those events? Good catch

Comment: @RobertAltman I suppose I could... Just wanted to keep it separate from my main form to keep my server code apart from my serial port code

Comment: No, I've used serial port for years, there's nothing more to do, set it's parameters, attach to DataReceived event and open it, nothing else. Also, the non-binary functions thend to have problems, the best is to use a loop while BytesToRead is greater than 0 (in this way you will consume any byte if it is received while you're processing the event), store it to an intermediate buffer (a list per example) and then check for the \r chars inside, whenever you find one extract from the buffer that segment of data, process it and repeat the operation until no \r is found on the buffer.

Comment: You could use this: 

string[] availablePports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

to get the list of the available ports and see if yours makes it in to the list.

Comment: I'm using that line above to populate a combobox with available ports in my application and then open the port that the user picks...

Comment: yeah I've already got that in my form. User selects from a combo box the port they want then they click open port and no problems. My issue is when I try to open the port on application launch I can't open it.

Comment: I get that. Hmm... well, either the port isn't available yet or something is different in the configuration. 
I would start by adding a Thread.Sleep(100) in the load method, right before you start all the serial port business. If that doesn't work, try stepping through your code and make sure all your variables for the port are accurate

Comment: @RobertAltman lol I was thinking of a thread.sleep... Let's see if it fixes anything

Comment: @RobertAltman nope, still persists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129383/discussion-between-robert-altman-and-j-doe).