# System.IO.IOException: The device is not ready, serial port config error

Tags: c#, winforms, io, serial-port, form-load

When my form loads I want to open a serial port. I know COM3 is already closed and I know it's the right name (I see my device as COM3 in device manager). This is my code:

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();

sp.PortName = "COM3";
sp.BaudRate = 2400;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend; //DO NOT SET TO NONE
sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

sp.Open();
```

however when I compile it I'm told the device isn't ready. How do I ready it?

Comment: When you *compile* it???  Surely not.  Wonky exceptions like that come from the port driver.  Get another one, spend more money.

Comment: Did you try communicating with your device with a serial port terminal tool like [Eltima's Serial Port Monitor](http://www.eltima.com/rs232-testing-software/) or [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @HebeleHododo Yes it works fine. I can even get it it to work on my own program if I open it with a button using the same code above^. It Just seems on startup of the program it times out or something and stops trying to open the port

Comment: @J.Doe I see in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875018/c-sharp-cant-open-serial-port-from-application-launch-successfully) that you got it to work with COM1. So, does this code work with COM1, but not with COM3?

Comment: @HebeleHododo Actually yeah I think it has nothing to do with the code at all. I just made an installer for my program, threw it up onto another computer and it works fine... Seems like the combination of my developement computer being on a VM and serial ports being buggy with VM ware computers that was causing it... Thanks for your help though. Appreciate it : )